# Orchard how to get module settings in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I got 2 kind of setting in my module.

1. Global settings (for the whole module)
2. Local settings (different for every widget)

Now I have a controller in wich I want both settings.

In controller I can get global settings like:

```
var globalSettings = Services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<Interspire_MailingSettingsPart>();
```

But how can I get local settings?

Both handlers:

- Global

  public class MailingSettingsHandler: ContentHandler
  {
      public MailingSettingsHandler(IRepository repository)
      {
          T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
          Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter("Site"));
          Filters.Add(new TemplateFilterForPart("Nastavitve", "Parts/MailingSettings", "Interspire"));
          Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
      }

  ```
  public Localizer T { get; set; }

  protected override void GetItemMetadata(GetContentItemMetadataContext context) {
      if (context.ContentItem.ContentType != "Site")
          return;
      base.GetItemMetadata(context);
      context.Metadata.EditorGroupInfo.Add(new GroupInfo(T("Interspire")));
  }
  ```

  }
- Local

  public class MailingHandler : ContentHandler
  {
      public MailingHandler(IRepository repository)
      {
          Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
      }
  }

EDIT:
Adding driver if it could help things:

```
public class MailingDriver : ContentPartDriver<Interspire_MailingPart>
{
    private readonly IOrchardServices _services;

    public MailingDriver(INotifier notifier, IOrchardServices services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(Interspire_MailingPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var mailingSettings = _services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<Interspire_MailingSettingsPart>();
        return ContentShape("Parts_Mailing",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Mailing(
                Url: mailingSettings.Url,
                SubscribeFormID: part.SubscribeFormID
            ));
    }

    //GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(Interspire_MailingPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Mailing_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/Mailing",
                Model: part,
                Prefix: Prefix));
        _services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<Interspire_MailingPart>() = part;
    }

    //POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(Interspire_MailingPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this post http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings (updated for 1.8+)

Comment: I made the settings by this post, but This are 2 different types! One is site settings (wich are in the post) and wich I can access from controller the other is local/widget settings wich I cannot access from controller because they are made differently from the global ones

Comment: When you cross-post, please include links.